# Filter by one-to-many relation based off of object count in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 4 models pertaining to restaurants and I'm having difficulty returning the correct results.

The models are `AdminEnteredRestaurant`, `Restaurant`, `Photo`, `Menu` and are defined as such:

```
class AdminEnteredRestaurant(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.OneToOneField(Restaurant)
    ...

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    ...

class Photo(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    ...

class Menu(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.OneToOneField(Restaurant)
    ...
```

The query I want is to filter all `AdminEnteredRestaurant`s and return only those `AdminEnteredRestaurant`s that have 1 or fewer `Photo`s and 0 Menus. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use [Count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#count), [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations), [lte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#lte) and [isnull](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-isnull) to make something like

```
from django.db.models import Count
results = AdminEnteredRestaurant.objects.annotate(num_photos=Count('restaurant__photo')) \
                                        .filter(num_photos__lte=1) \
                                        .filter(restaurant__menu__isnull =True)
```

Comment: This looks like it could work. However, what if I wanted to also filter for menu is lte=1 as well?

Comment: You can chain `.annotate()`.  So, here, you'd add another `.annotate` like `.annotate(num_menus=Count('menu'))` then change the filter to `.filter(num_menus__lte=1)`

Comment: Ok, great! This worked perfectly. Your code is incorrect, however. Please update and I will upvote it. It should look like this: AdminEnteredRestaurant.objects.annotate(num_photos=Count('restaurant__photo')) \
                                        .filter(num_photos__lte=1) \
                                        .filter(restaurant__menu__isnull=True)